# Removing indexes from a 3D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

From an image I need to remove one pixel from each row. So for an image that is `50 x 60`, I have to remove `50` pixels from the image. The locations of pixels is already determined and is available as the index list in the form:

```
[(0, 6), (1,2), (2,9), (3,12), .... , (49,23)]
```

where `(0,6)` for example could be read as, delete the pixel that occurs at 0th row and 6th column. How could I remove the corresponding pixels from 3-channel (colored) image?

I know the way of deleting from a 2-D array like:

```
np.delete(gray_image[0], 6)
np.delete(gray_image[1], 2)
np.delete(gray_image[2], 9)
.
.
np.delete(gray_image[49], 23)
```

But how can I do this on an image which has 3 channels (3D array)?

Comment: what is shape of your 3D array and how is your index for deleting

Comment: @DevKhadka The shape of 3D array is (640, 340, 3) and index is a 1D array of length 640.

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you? If so, consider accepting one of those? Like-wise on your previous question too - https://stackoverflow.com/q/58155451/.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58079918/), we will extend it to `3D` array case, while keeping in mind that row would mean the first axis for `3D` image arrays and columns would be the second one. So, deleting one element per row, would give us one element less along the second axis.

The solution would look something like this -

```
def delete_per_row_3D(a, remove_idx):
    mask = np.ones(a.shape[:-1],dtype=bool)
    mask[np.arange(len(remove_idx)), remove_idx] = False
    return a[mask].reshape(np.array(a.shape)-[0,1,0])
```

Sample run -

```
In [43]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: a = np.random.randint(10,100,(2,4,3))

In [44]: a
Out[44]: 
array([[[54, 57, 74],
        [77, 77, 19],
        [93, 31, 46],
        [97, 80, 98]],

       [[98, 22, 68],
        [75, 49, 97],
        [56, 98, 91],
        [47, 35, 87]]])

In [45]: remove_idx = np.array([2,0]) # length be a.shape[0],
         # as no. of rows in 3D image array would be that

In [46]: delete_per_row_3D(a, remove_idx)
Out[46]: 
array([[[54, 57, 74],
        [77, 77, 19],
        [97, 80, 98]],

       [[75, 49, 97],
        [56, 98, 91],
        [47, 35, 87]]])
```

**Visualize with channels**

To help the readers visualize it better, consider the three slices for RGB/BGR channels -

```
In [47]: a[...,0]
Out[47]: 
array([[54, 77, 93, 97],
       [98, 75, 56, 47]])

In [48]: a[...,1]
Out[48]: 
array([[57, 77, 31, 80],
       [22, 49, 98, 35]])

In [49]: a[...,2]
Out[49]: 
array([[74, 19, 46, 98],
       [68, 97, 91, 87]])
```

We want to delete the `column-2` from the first row and `column-0` from the second row. So, consider those being removed from all three channels, i.e. `93,31,46` and `98,22,68` removed. Thus, we will end up with the shown output earlier with one element less along the second axis.

**Alternatives**

Again from the earlier linked post, two more alternatives would be -

```
def delete_per_row_3D_v2(a, remove_idx):
    mask = remove_idx[:,None]!=np.arange(a.shape[1])
    return a[mask].reshape(np.array(a.shape)-[0,1,0])

def delete_per_row_3D_v3(a, remove_idx):
    m,n = a.shape[:-1]
    rm = remove_idx+n*np.arange(m)
    return np.delete(a.reshape(-1,a.shape[-1]),rm,axis=0).reshape(m,n-1,-1)
```

**Push it to the next level with view-based approach**

We will leverage view-based method to mask pixels in a *group-based* manner and hence achieve major benefits on memory and hence performance, as shown below -

```
def delete_per_row_3D_view(a, remove_idx):
    m,n,r = a.shape
    mask = np.ones((m,n),dtype=bool)
    mask[np.arange(len(remove_idx)), remove_idx] = False
    vd = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * r))
    a_masked = a.view(vd).ravel()[mask.flat].view(a.dtype)
    return a_masked.reshape(m,-1,r)
```

#### Benchmarking

We are including all vectorized methods here (including all from this post and from @Paul Panzer's post).

1) OP's 640x340 3D array case :

```
In [180]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.randint(0,256,(640,340,3)).astype(np.uint8)
     ...: remove_idx = np.random.randint(0,340,(640))

In [181]: %timeit delete_per_row_3D(a, remove_idx)
     ...: %timeit delete_per_row_3D_v2(a, remove_idx)
     ...: %timeit delete_per_row_3D_v3(a, remove_idx)
     ...: %timeit delete_per_row_3D_view(a, remove_idx)
     ...: %timeit pp(a, remove_idx)
     ...: %timeit pp_flat(a, remove_idx)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.09 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 5.31 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.58 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 211 µs per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 4.19 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.23 ms per loop
```

2) Small 64x34 3D array case :

```
In [182]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.randint(0,256,(64,34,3)).astype(np.uint8)
     ...: remove_idx = np.random.randint(0,34,(64))

In [183]: %timeit delete_per_row_3D(a, remove_idx)
     ...: %timeit delete_per_row_3D_v2(a, remove_idx)
     ...: %timeit delete_per_row_3D_v3(a, remove_idx)
     ...: %timeit delete_per_row_3D_view(a, remove_idx)
     ...: %timeit pp(a, remove_idx)
     ...: %timeit pp_flat(a, remove_idx)
10000 loops, best of 3: 61.9 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 61.7 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 61.3 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.9 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 49.8 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.2 µs per loop
```

3) Large 6400x3400 3D array case :

```
In [184]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.randint(0,256,(6400,3400,3)).astype(np.uint8)
     ...: remove_idx = np.random.randint(0,3400,(6400))

In [185]: %timeit delete_per_row_3D(a, remove_idx)
     ...: %timeit delete_per_row_3D_v2(a, remove_idx)
     ...: %timeit delete_per_row_3D_v3(a, remove_idx)
     ...: %timeit delete_per_row_3D_view(a, remove_idx)
     ...: %timeit pp(a, remove_idx)
     ...: %timeit pp_flat(a, remove_idx)
1 loop, best of 3: 649 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 669 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 434 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 47.5 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 415 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 127 ms per loop
```

So, `view-based` method : `delete_per_row_3D_view` is blowing away all other approaches across all sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/58157198/7207392

```
import numpy as np
import operator as op

a = np.arange(60.0).reshape(4,5,3)
idxs = [(0,1), (1,3), (2, 1), (3,4)]

m,n,_ = a.shape

# extract column indices
# there are simpler ways but this is fast
columns = np.fromiter(map(op.itemgetter(1),idxs),int,m)

# build decimated array
result = np.where((columns[...,None]>np.arange(n-1))[...,None],a[:,:-1],a[:,1:])
```

If you want it as fast as possible it may be worthwhile temporarily merging the last two dimensions -(`pp_flat` vs `pp` in these timings):

Update: Never discount @Divakar (new entry `delete_per_row_3D_view`)...

[image]

If you are wondering about that zigzag just below 10^3 that is where I switch from image decimation to repeating pixels. The latter generates contiguous arrays. Interestingly a 4 times larger contiguous array is processed faster than a smaller noncontiguous one ... (More precisely, the method doesn't work on noncontiguous arrays, so we have to make a contiguous copy)

UPDATE: added a version that can handle noncontiguous arrays as long as the color triplets are contiguous.

Code:

```
from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder, MultiArgument
import numpy as np
import operator as op
from scipy.misc import face

B = BenchmarkBuilder()

@B.add_function()
def delete_per_row_3D(a, remove_idx):
    mask = np.ones(a.shape[:-1],dtype=bool)
    mask[np.arange(len(remove_idx)), remove_idx] = False
    return a[mask].reshape(np.array(a.shape)-[0,1,0])

@B.add_function()
def delete_per_row_3D_v2(a, remove_idx):
    mask = remove_idx[:,None]!=np.arange(a.shape[1])
    return a[mask].reshape(np.array(a.shape)-[0,1,0])

@B.add_function()
def delete_per_row_3D_v3(a, remove_idx):
    m,n = a.shape[:-1]
    rm = remove_idx+n*np.arange(m)
    return np.delete(a.reshape(-1,a.shape[-1]),rm,axis=0).reshape(m,n-1,-1)

@B.add_function()
def pp(a,columns):
    m,n,_ = a.shape
    return np.where((columns[...,None]>np.arange(n-1))[...,None],a[:,:-1],a[:,1:])

@B.add_function()
def pp_flat(a,columns):
    m,n,d = a.shape
    af = a.reshape(m,-1)
    return np.where(columns[...,None]>np.arange(n-1).repeat(d),af[...,:-d],af[...,d:]).reshape(m,n-1,d)


@B.add_function()
def delete_per_row_3D_view(a, remove_idx):
    m,n,r = a.shape
    mask = np.ones((m,n),dtype=bool)
    mask[np.arange(len(remove_idx)), remove_idx] = False
    vd = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * r))
    a_masked = np.ascontiguousarray(a).view(vd).ravel()[mask.flat].view(a.dtype)
    return a_masked.reshape(m,-1,r)


from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

@B.add_function()
def delete_per_row_3D_view_2(a, remove_idx):
    m,n,r = a.shape
    mask = np.ones((m,n),dtype=bool)
    mask[np.arange(len(remove_idx)), remove_idx] = False
    vd = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * r))
    a_masked = as_strided(a[0,0,...].view(vd),a.shape[:-1],a.strides[:-1])[mask].view(a.dtype)
    return a_masked.reshape(m,-1,r)

@B.add_arguments('array size')
def argument_provider():
    orig = face()
    for dec in (128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1,-2,-4):
        if dec>0:
            a = orig[::dec,::dec]
        else:
            a = orig.repeat(-dec,axis=0).repeat(-dec,axis=1)
        dim_size,w,_ = a.shape
        idxs = np.random.randint(0,w,dim_size)
#        idxs = [*enumerate(np.random.randint(0,w,dim_size)),]
        yield dim_size, MultiArgument([a,idxs])

r = B.run()
r.plot()

import pylab
pylab.savefig('delunif.png')
```

Comment: Thanks for pushing me! Came up with a view-based one that's blowing away all others.

Comment: @Divakar That's the spirit! I'll add it to the timings.

Comment: @Divakar Is there a way of making it work on noncontiguous arrays? Your method wins most of the time even where it has to make a copy, but I was wondering if there is a better way. As long as the last dim is contiguous numpy shouldn't be so squeamish...

Comment: AFAIK those view based ones need them to be contiguous. So, I don't think there's any. But again, I don't know all ins and outs of NumPy.

Comment: @Divakar If the last dim is contiguous perhaps with `as_strided`, but not sure it's worth the trouble.

Comment: @Divakar It works! And only marginally slower on contiguous arrays. See updated post.

Answer (score 0):

you can delete the pixels by calculating 1D index of each pixel to be deleted from your index list like below and then delete elements using the index then reshaping back array to new size

```py
ar = np.arange(60).reshape(5,4,3)
indx = [(0,3), (1,1), (2,0), (3,2), (4,1)]
indx_1d = [ar.shape[2]*ar.shape[1]*i+ar.shape[2]*j + k for item in indx for k,(i,j) in enumerate([item]*3)]

deleted = np.delete(ar, indx_1d).reshape(5,3,3)

print(ar)
print("\n\n******************************")
print(deleted)
```

**Output**

```
[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]
  [ 9 10 11]]

 [[12 13 14]
  [15 16 17]
  [18 19 20]
  [21 22 23]]

 [[24 25 26]
  [27 28 29]
  [30 31 32]
  [33 34 35]]

 [[36 37 38]
  [39 40 41]
  [42 43 44]
  [45 46 47]]

 [[48 49 50]
  [51 52 53]
  [54 55 56]
  [57 58 59]]]


******************************
[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]]

 [[12 13 14]
  [18 19 20]
  [21 22 23]]

 [[27 28 29]
  [30 31 32]
  [33 34 35]]

 [[36 37 38]
  [39 40 41]
  [45 46 47]]

 [[48 49 50]
  [54 55 56]
  [57 58 59]]]
```